# Outputting stored procedure results

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-express

Apologies if this is somewhat of an elementary question... .net newb here thrown in at the deep end.

I have created a stored procedure to return a record which I am executing as below. When I inspect "r" with a breakpoint in Visual Studio express, my data is returned correctly.

MyPage.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var dd = dealerDetails();
}

protected DataTable dealerDetails()
{
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlCommand cmd;

    using (cn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Server.ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("spMyStoredProcedure", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strslug", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = Page.Request.QueryString["_slug"];
        JJ.Diagnostics.Tracer.Trace(cmd);
        try
        {
            IDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read())
            {
                ??????
            }

            r.Close();
            return ?????;

        }
        catch (SqlException exSql)
        {
            // Make an event log entry of the exception
            EventLogController.LogException(exSql);
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Make an event log entry of the exception
            EventLogController.LogException(ex);
            throw;
        }

    }


}
```

When I simply try to return r, I get an error:

> Cannot inplicityly convert type 'System.Data.IDataReader' to 'System.Data.DataTable'. 
>   An explicity conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I would like to be able to access the results from this stored procedure in MyPage.aspx. I'd assume that I could do this with `<%=dd.propname%>` am I correct in this or would it require any additional steps?

Please let me know if I've ommited any important information here.

Comment: An honest piece of advice - especially since you're learning .net so it's hopefully easier for you to establish a good/bad habit. Do try to use more descriptive variable names - there's no reason to minify C#.

Answer (score 3):

Use a data adapter to fill a data table and return that. If your stored procedure is returning only the data that is required. I don't see any reason to iterate through every column and explicitly define them. A `SqlDataAdapter` will fill a `DataTable` for you without hard coding and adding the row values.

[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is some reading and examples of `SqlDataAdapters`.

```
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Entire Code:

```
// Utilize the using directive on any disposable objects so you aren't 
// left with garbage.
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Settings.Server.ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spMyStoredProcedure", cn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    // define your parameter here, just personal preference, but makes debugging 
    //easier in my opinion.
    string slug = Page.Request.QueryString["_slug"];
    // Use the newer .AddWithValue command.
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strslug", slug);
    JJ.Diagnostics.Tracer.Trace(cmd);

    try
    {
        // SqlDataAdapter will automatically open/close your connection for you, 
        // however, for future reference, try to open your connection only when 
        // it is required to be opened. This will reduce your connection time/
        // server strain.
        // cn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, cn)
        {
            // Data adapter will automatically fill your returned data table.
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("TableName");
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException exSql)
    {
        // Make an event log entry of the exception
        EventLogController.LogException(exSql);
        throw;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Make an event log entry of the exception
        EventLogController.LogException(ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

From this point you may access your data like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dd = dealerDetails();
    // if more than one row is expected you can use the for loop
    // if not, just access them directly.
    for (int i = 0; i < d.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        // Jump straight to here if you are positive you will only 
        // return 1 row of data.
        string ColumnName1 = dd.Rows[i]["ColumnName1"].ToString();
        string ColumnName2 = dd.Rows[i]["ColumnName2"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly would this accomplish, apart from going against SOLID?

Comment: @decPL How exactly does this 'go... against SOLID'?

Comment: *One should “Depend upon Abstractions. Do not depend upon concretions.”* And even if you disregard it as a guideline, not rule (which is obviously true) - your answer still doesn't do anything to fix the OP's problem.

Comment: @aw04 Question updated. Why would you go through the extra steps of hard coding in the field names and adding rows. If your procedure is returning the correct values, you can just fill and return a data table. :p

Comment: @Volearix Yeah, I'm not really familiar with DataTable that's why I didn't answer. This now looks better than my suggestion.

Comment: @decPL I misread the question the first time/ didn't read it all the way through. See this question quite often on here.

Answer (score 2):

According to your `dealerDetails` method signature - return value is `DataTable`. So you can't return `DataReader` because it is not derived from DataTable.

You need to create DataTable and its columns, and fill table while reading from dataReader.

Something like this

```
using(var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Column1_Name", typeof(column1_Type));
    dt.Columns.Add("Column2_Name", typeof(column2_Type));

    while (r.Read())
    {
        var dro = dt.NewRow();
        dro["Column1_Name"] = somevalue_from_reader;
        dro["Column2_Name"] = somevalue_from_reader;
        dt.Rows.Add(dro);
    }

    r.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: As OP is new to .NET, it might be useful to go the extra length and show him the `using` directive.

Comment: @AndyKorneyev Or just do `dt.Load(r);`

Comment: Thank you. In this circumstance, is returning a DataTable the way to go or is there a better way to do it? I'm not constricted to using a datatable at all, I came across an example and implemented it this way and it returned the data from the SP so I stuck with it. Cheers

Comment: @Fraser You can read the data into a custom class or whatever you need. Really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @aw04 The stored procedure simply returns a single row from the database relating to a business branch. I need to pass the results of this query to the .aspx page so I can access the values. Cheers

Comment: @Fraser I've always created a custom class for this purpose. Works great and is easy to read/understand. Can't comment on the DataTable approach as I've never used it, though. Not sure what advantage it would bring here, if any.